# Можно сделать треугольник в CSS?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, html, clip-path

Нужно нарисовать треугольник на CSS.
Способы которые описаны в статьях используют border, визуально они как треугольник, но внутри нельзя поместить элементы.

Можно сделать треугольник но чтобы внутри можно было поместить элементы?

Приведу пример как должен быть результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SVG` или `clip-path`

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Да

Comment: @Arthur а можно сделать как-то чтобы текст начался где начинается треугольник?

Comment: Может быть Вы @МаксимЛенский знаете?

Comment: Вот пример https://codepen.io/vodnicear/pen/KeBeMg

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а можете скинуть пример с SVG?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский дело в том что размеры картинок я не знаю, получаю их с сервера, они могут быть разными размерами и хочу через https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html ранжировать их

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Спасибо!

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Вы действительно нашли способ сделать треугольник, всё прекрасно, но есть один нюанс: возможно сделать так чтобы в код не писать координаты где должны отображаться картинки? нужно чтобы они как в div-е друг за другом шли, по умолчанию, реально вообще это сделать?

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear, не получиться. Нужно писать JS который будет расставлять вложенные IMG внутри треугольника. Причем чем больше IMG тем шире или выше JS придется его растянуть. Огромное количество кода.

Answer (score 1):

как и писал Arthur в комментарии, можно использовать clip-path, но расположение элементов надо будет подгонять вручную

```css
.a {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 00%, 100% 50%, 0% 50%, 0% 50%);
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img src="//www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

`https://codepen.io/MaxManchak/pen/pKZVpo`

Comment: проблема в том что картинка заходит под край треугольника, position: absolute в данном случае не могу использовать